# Correct term for “string consisting of words”

Tags: terminology, strings, computational-linguistics

In a paper I am writing I want to make distinction between (1) *string consisting of any characters* and (2) *string consisting of a chain of words from known language, with possible delimiters*. My intuitive idea is to simply use *string* for meaning (1) and *text* for meaning (2). It sounds a bit naive, but this terminology could work, given that I define it properly in my paper.

Yet I have an uneasy feeling that meaning (2) has fancier name in fields of computer science or computational linguistics. So, what are the precise terms to make distinction between the two types of strings?

**UPDATE**

Suppose we have an alphabet `Σ = {a, b, c, ~}`, where `~` is a delimiter symbol, and language `L = {aaa, bbb, abc}`.

Now, the following strings satisfy definition (1), but **not** (2):

- *cba*
- *a*
- *aaaa*
- *a~b~~*

And the following strings would satisfy **both** definitions (because they are made of the words of language L).

- *aaabbbabc*
- *abc*
- *aaa~bbb~aaa~~~aaa*
- *~*
- (an empty string)

In some applications my strings could be actual text in a human language like English, Lithuanian or Esperanto. But this is not required. It could also be a DNA chain, a binary file, or anything else. Also keep in mind, that in practical applications the strings would most likely be long (like a journal article, or entire corpus for that matter), so calling it a "sentence" would be a bit of understatement. Meaning of the text is entirely irrelevant here.

So, regarding definition (1) all is clear - I just call it a *string* on alphabet Σ. Now the core question is this: what do I call the strings from the second example to make them distinct from the first example. My initial idea is to call it a "text". One of the answers proposed "word string", which I like even better. Maybe you have seen other terms being used for such purpose in the literature?

It might seem that I'm in extreme hair splitting mode here. Yet that term will be all over my PhD thesis, very likely including the title. Therefore I really want to get my terminology straight.

Comment: Seems to me that both are strings over two different alphabets. The first being characters; the second being words. So you can use the same definition and change the alphabet.

Comment: Let us assume that the same alphabet is used in both cases.

Comment: Perhaps a "sentence?"

Comment: @jmite I remember reading "sentential form" somewhere.

Comment: My string could potentially be very long, so "sentence" would sound a bit strange. And "sentential form" seems to be something entirely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If definition (1) is intended for any sequence of characters, I would
simply call it *string* as you suggest, but I would call it *word* or
*lexeme* if it is intended to be words of a language.

Regarding definition (2), it depends again on what you are expecting
to consider. If it is any sequence of words, usually meaningless, with
a variety of separators, the name *text* would do fine, and I would
not worry too much about computational linguistic since the only
meaningless piece of text that matters in CL is "*[Colorless green ideas
sleep furiously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)*".

If it is actually intended to be a sentence of a language, then you
might call it *sentence*. I feel that *text* would rather be used for
larger pieces of discourse. You should be careful though that is is
not confused with *sentence* meaning a string of words. Speech
processing people may speak of *utterance*, but it may be
inappropriate for your use. They use also *sentence*, which they
structure into *word lattice* when the separators are not clearly
identified, which amounts to a *word sequence* or *word string* if they
are clearly identified.

This disctinction may also depend on whether your separators are one or
many, and whether they have a role.

In other words, it is hard to give you a precise answer without more
details on what you are doing. I first tried, and then realized that
it led me to make unwarranted assumptions about what you are doing.

The one thing that is really important is that you are very clear
about your definitions. And if you can motivate your terminology
choices, that may help the reader. I am still wondering why the *borogoves* had to be so *mimsy*.

Comment: I like "word string", I might use it, or stay with "text". Well, as usually my professor will have the final say on this one.

I am going to illustrate my question with some examples, maybe that will help to clarify.

Comment: @ViliusNormantas As I said, "word string" runs the risk of ambiguity, since I would
personally understand it as a string on an alphabet consisting of
words, i.e. a string of strings, rather than a string in which
separator symbols delimit substrings (which seems to be what you are
after). But short of knowing more precisely what you are doing, I
cannot be much more help. But choosing names and their meanings is the author's privilege, within reason (and supervision :).

Comment: Dictionary defines "word string" as "a linear sequence of words as spoken or written" (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word+string). Almost what I want. Yet in my case the words are concatenated into one big string (with possible delimiters).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are defining sets using your definition. It is obvious that the set defined by (2) is a subset of the set you are defining by (1) right now. But that is offtopic.

I am quite sure that there is no fancy word for what you are calling a text, since your definition is very vague. As a text you are defining a list of words contained in a dictionary, separated by delimiters. I would certainly not call this a text. If your "text" has a meaning which is based on an under-laying grammar you can call it a sentence, a statement or a paragraph.

Comment: Yes, string by definition (2) is also a string by definition (1), assuming that both consist of symbols from the same alphabet.

My strings could be very long, so it would be a bit bizarre to call them a sentence, or a paragraph. Yes, in some applications the text could be actual human readable text with meaning, etc. But that is not relevant to my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). It has a Machine Learning connotation as it is where the concept is used, though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to quite answer the question, since a bag of words is explicitly a multiset, whereas the objects being manipulated here is a string. On the other hand, perhaps it suggests "string of words" as a good choice for the object under consideration, by analogy with "bag of words".

Comment: @DavidRicherby The problem is that *string of words* may also be more
naturally understood as a string on an alphabet composed of words,
which is actually closer to the concept of *bag of words*, but is not
what the OP is considering, namely a unique string with words as
substrings, rather than a string of strings. This is precisely the
confusion I am worried about in my own answer. It is not too much of a
problem if only one of the two concepts is actually used by the OP,
which I doubt, though the analogy with *bag of words* does not seem really adequate.

Comment: My bad, indeed bag of words is not correct. Maybe *word n-gram* would be what the OP wants? Though again this'd normally mean a sequence that does exist in a given reference text or corpus.

Comment: No, as you have said yourself, what I want is not a bag of words.